# Reconfigure each time - PhpStorrm

Tags: phpstorm

I am making all the settings of the PHPStorm software and when i reset, I set up FTP settings again every time and I can not see the last open files

For example, each time; `Tools > Options > "Upload changed files automatically to the default server"` .. I am setting this option every time.

I've never experienced this before.
What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Do you use Settings Repository or Settings Sync features? Is `.idea` folder under VCS or not?

Comment: such problems may occur if the project is located on Onedrive, for example; if it's the case, please try moving your project to a local folder that is not part of Onedrive sync

Comment: @lena Yes I use OneDrive, Is there a way to run it on OneDrive?

Comment: onedrive sync often causes issues saving .idea files; you can move .idea files to a local folder that is not part of Onedrive sync, keeping sources on Onedrive: create a new empty project in the preferred location on your local drive, and then link your source folder located on Onedrive to it by adding it as a content root in Settings | Directories, Add Content Root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such problems may occur if the project is located on OneDrive; you can move `.idea` files to a local folder that is not part of OneDrive sync, keeping sources on OneDrive: create a new empty project in the preferred location on your local drive, and then link your source folder located on OneDrive to it by adding it as a content root in **Settings | Directories, Add Content Root**

Comment: Thank you for idea!